# Why does "array[index]" return "nil"?

Tags: lua

this problem seems very simple but I cannot find a solution for it, actually I don't even know what is wrong!!!

So basically I have this Lua code:

```
io.write("\nPlease provide the message to be decyphered: ")
message = io.read()
seq = #message
ffib = {}
a = 0
b = 1
c = a + b
fib = 0
while c < (seq - 10) do
    fib = fib + 1
    ffib[fib] = c
    a = b
    b = c
    c = a + b
end
decyphered = ""
for i = 1,seq do
    decyphered = table.concat{decyphered, message:sub(ffib[i],ffib[i])}
end
io.write("\nDecyphered message: ", decyphered, "\n\n")
```

and trying to access `ffib[fib]` returns `nil`. So trying to `message:sub(ffib[i]...` later throws an error.
When I try accessing `ffib`'s values manually, `ffib[1]` for example, it works alright, it's only when trying to access it with an iterator that it screws up.

Somewhere else in my code I have this:

```
io.write("\nPlease provide the message to be cyphered: ")
message = io.read()
cyphered = ""
seq = #message
ffib = {}
a = 0
b = 1
c = a + b
for fib = 1,seq do
    ffib[fib] = c
    a = b
    b = c
    c = a + b
end
```

which is basically the same thing but instead of using a while loop, it uses a for loop, and it works just fine!

Please help me solve this I am going insane.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the algorithm, but right now you generate an insufficient amount of Fibonacci numbers. For strings less than 12 bytes you don't generate any at all. Therefore you can't iterate over your full message.

Comment: Considering that you use your fibonacci numbers to index the message later on, why don't you use `while c < #message` as condition in your while-loop? That will generate fibonacci numbers up to the message length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out!

```
io.write("\nPlease provide the message to be decyphered: ")
message = io.read()
seq = #message
ffib = {}
a = 0
b = 1
c = a + b
fib = 0
while c < (seq - 10) do
    fib = fib + 1
    ffib[fib] = c
    a = b
    b = c
    c = a + b
end
decyphered = ""
for i = 1,seq do <--------------
    decyphered = table.concat{decyphered, message:sub(ffib[i],ffib[i])}
end
io.write("\nDecyphered message: ", decyphered, "\n\n")
```

I was using the wrong variable in the for loop, so it was looping through the entire message length instead of the fibonacci array length, the "nil" values were indexes out of bounds!

To correct this, I simply changed `seq` for `#ffib` in that For Loop, marked by an arrow.

Thanks everyone who tried to help me anyway!

Answer (score 0):

this part doesn't make much sense I think

```
while c < (seq - 10) do
```

Why the minus 10? `ffib` will have less entries than `seq` while in the loop after that you expect a value in `ffib` from 1 to `seq`

And even if you change it to

```
while c < seq do
```

Then there still won't be enough for messages larger than length 2.

If anything, you might want to do

```
while c < (seq + 10) do
```

But even there you will run into an issue when the message is a certain length.

I'm also not familiar with that algorithm, but it looks pretty weird to me and I wonder what it actually establishes

Comment: I suppose the algorithm is supposed to generate fibonacci numbers up to the message length which are then used to index the message string. Perhaps they also tried to implement a [fibonacci-shifted caesar cipher](https://github.com/keithieopia/fibonacci-caesar-cipher)?

Comment: I'm so sorry I forgot to mention, during the encryption of the message, 10 additional characters are inserted at the end, that's why I'm subtracting 10 from "seq". I don't the problem lies here, though. As I said, when storing the values into the array it works fine, it's just when *accessing* them through an iterator that it returns "nil". At least that's what I've gathered from debugging, if anyone has a more sensible explanation, please share!